# How do you extract a particular directory from a multi-part RAR using unrar CLI

Tags: command-line, rar

I can't find any way to do this after searching for hours and trying various things. I'm using rarlab's free unrar CLI on OS X. I want to extract a single folder and its contents, preserving paths, from a multi-part RAR archive. Seems like a simple enough task but… The help listing is of no help. Someone must have figured this out by now.

Comment: I didn't include anything I tried because nothing worked. I don't want people to have to wade through posts to get to the code listing that works. I think in a case like this, someone either knows how to do this or they don't pretty much. But if you insist, the only thing I tried that might be relevant is:  
  
  `unrar l -ap/dir1 filename.part*.rar`  
  
and variations of this.  
  
I got the '-ap' switch from the unrar help listing:  
  
  `ap<path>      Set path inside archive`.  
  
Kind of vague at best but the only thing that seems like it might work.

Comment: So much to say; so little space. First of all, I don’t know what you mean by “I don't want people to have to wade through posts to get to the code listing that works.” Secondly, members of Super User like to see what you’ve tried (1) so we know that you’re invested in the question, and you aren’t just asking us to “do your homework for you,” (2) because it might clarify your problem, and (3) so we can avoid suggesting solutions that have already failed for you. Next … OK, I’m running out of room here, and this is looking more and more like an answer, so I’m going to post the rest as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, well many times on these forums, I find a long thread with lots of code blocks that I have to wade through before I get to the right one that has the answer. There's what the OP tried, then someone else's speculative code, then yet another one's speculative code. It's not obvious which one is the final solution so you have to read many posts before you find the right one. I hoped to avoid that. (part 1)

Comment: As far as your comment (1) about being 'invested', as you put it, or asking you to do my homework, I find that a bit offhanded. I think "after searching for hours and trying various things" clearly indicates my efforts and I shouldn't have to be questioned further about that. As for (2), maybe… I'm not sure about (3) because I think someone either knows this or they don't. Certainly people have encountered this problem and have learned to deal with it and can just give an answer without speculating. At least that's what I was hoping for. (part 2)

Comment: It may shock you to learn this, but some people lie. If you hang around Super User long enough to earn some [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/reputation), people may be more inclined to take you at your word.

Answer (score 4):

I had the answer in a comment so I will list it properly as an answer:

Answer:

```
unrar x volname.part001.rar /dir1/*
```

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

`unrar(1)` refers to `/usr/doc/rar/Rar.Txt`.  I found two different versions of it,
[here](http://www.anfora.es/descargas/UTILIDADES/Rar.txt)
and [here](http://home.aubg.bg/students/MRT090/Rar.txt). 
Both of them say, “When extracting or testing a multi-volume archive
you must use only the first volume name.” 
So, I guess you shouldn’t be saying `filename.part*.rar`. 
Which raises the question: can you even list the (complete) archive? 
Because, if you get stuck on something tricky, you should back off
and try something simpler (crawl before you walk) to narrow down where the problem is. 
That said, I would suggest something like

```
unrar e volname.part001.rar dir1
```

or

```
unrar e volname.part001.rar dir1/
```

or

```
unrar e volname.part001.rar "dir1/*"
```

---

**<edit>**

or

```
unrar e volname.part001.rar  dir1/*
```

(same as the previous one, but without quotes) which is what ultimately worked for the OP.

**</edit>**

---

Use `x` (for e**x**tract) instead of `e` (for **e**xtract) if that works better for you. `dir1` should maybe begin with a slash if that’s how the files appear in the archive.

Comment: No, I don't have unrar(1). I mentioned that I'm using rarlab's own free unrar CLI, [RAR 5.01 beta 1 for Mac OS X](http://www.rarlab.com/rar/rarosx-5.0.1b1.tar.gz).

Yes I can list out the contents of the archives by giving just the first archive name.

I spent hours trying various permutations of what you suggested.
(part 1)

Comment: `unrar x volname.part001.rar dir1` yields:

> Extracting from volname.part001.rar    
> Extracting from volname.part002.rar  
  
> No files to extract  
  
`unrar x volname.part001.rar dir1/`:  

> makes dir1 and extracts all files and their directories to it

`unrar x volname.part001.rar "dir1/*"` yields:

> Extracting from volname.part001.rar  
> Extracting from volname.part002.rar
  
> No files to extract
(part 2)  
(Formatting does not seem to work.)

Comment: The docs you reference are for older versions of the rarlab rar CLI but the syntax applies to unrar as well. I checked my download directory and the doc for version 5.0 is there. This document is far more detailed than the help listing. Stripped of all other options, the syntax for extracting particular files, and presumably directories, is:

"unrar <command> <archive> <files...>"

The example in the doc is helpful:

> extract *.txt from docs.rar

`rar x docs.rar *.txt`

So, piecing it all together:

`unrar x volname.part001.rar /dir1/*`

did the trick.

Comment: Answer:  
  
`unrar x volname.part001.rar /dir1/*`
  
Thanks for the input. The documentation helped a lot.

Comment: I’m surprised that it works without quotes, but not with, on OS X. That’s the sort of behavior that I would expect from Windows. I’m glad I could point you in the right direction.

Comment: If you want to help future seekers of knowledge, click on the checkmark to the left of my answer, to mark it as your “accepted” answer. (I’ve taken the liberty of editing it to include the variant that worked for you.) When your reputation reaches 15, you will be able to vote “up” for good answers –– multiple per question, on your own question(s) and others’. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) in the [Asking](http://superuser.com/help/asking) section of the Super User [Help Center](http://superuser.com/help) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to extract rar file in destination directory

### unrar -x rarfileName.rar destinationDir

I did it in Linux RHEL 6.2

Comment: Doesn't that extract everything into a specified directory?  The question is how to extract only a specific folder from within a multi-part .rar file and preserve the original path.

Comment: Of course it does and it is a wrong answer. The correct answer is already given.

Comment: It doesn't. It's should be just `x`, not `-x`.